# What is a maximum g force value possible to simulate with a phone in a hand?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am writing a simple f1 g force meter for android using accelerometer. Everything looks fine but the only problem is that the maximum value I can simulate is 2.85. Probably I do something wrong because it is simple to "make" for example 2.5 g, but using all my strength I can't have 3g.

That is how I calculate g value:

```
double x = event.values[0];
double y = event.values[1];
double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
double currentG = (a/ SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need I can add more code.

Comment: I guess you should ask NASA for their centrifuge.

Comment: Groan ... that is terrible :-)

Comment: The question wasn't accurate... I don't need MAXIMUM value. I just wanted to know if I calculate a value correctly. It just looks like it stopps on 2.85 and it was strange for me. And of course I am not destroying my phone if you didn't get it.

Comment: @user1351285 - if you don't destroy your phone, how are you going to know for sure?  C'mon, do it for science!! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here are some suggestions:

- Work out more.  Build up those arm muscles.
- Tie a strong cord to your phone and swing it round and round really fast.  (And don't let go ... if there are any small children or pets around.  Or wide-screen TVs.)
- Build something like a potato cannon.  (Hold the kids and pets too.)
- Drop your phone onto a hard surface from a significant height.

But seriously, many / most scenarios that involve large acceleration have a significant risk of destroying your phone ... and they will probably void your warranty.  **Don't blame me!!**

---

It is also possible that your phone's accelerometer is only capable of measuring acceleration up to a certain level.  For instance, if it involves measuring the deflection of a sprung lever, the lever could well have a physical limiter to protect it against damage.

Hint: Have you tried reading the phone's technical specifications?  Trawling the manufacturer's website?

Comment: Well... that's all I knew, but it was just strange for me, that I can easy do 2,6g and 2,9 is impossible. But anyway thank you...

Comment: if you drop your phone on a hard surface there are much more than 2.9g but the sensors mounted in cells are not built for crash- but posture-evaluation- I guess you mobile doesn't have airbags!?

Comment: I know nothing about the acelerometer, but +1 for that answer! :D

Comment: Dropping it on hard surface would result in acceleration pick, that would be much more than 3G but would last probably too short to measure. The trick with swinging is the best, since it produces constant acceleration. It could be worth trying to attach the line to mixer or drill.